# Password buffer

Tags: c

```
void _password(char buffer[])
{

    char c;
    int pos = 0;
    int a = 0;
    do
    {

        c = getch();

        if( c==' ')
        {
            printf("\a");
        }
        else if( isprint(c) )
        {
            buffer[ pos++ ] = c;
            printf("%c", '*');
        }
        else if( c == 8 && pos )
        {
            buffer[ pos-- ] = '\0';
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
        }
    }
    while( c != 13 );

}
```

When I use the  code in my project to buffer passwords, if i press wrong password first time and then if i press right password it show right password wrong .. i used this code as a function ..

Comment: What? Can you please re-read your question, and see if *you* can understand it?

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You should predecrement to erase the character in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append a null terminator to a buffer.

```
    ...
    while (c != 13);
    buffer[pos] = '\0'; // Here
}
```